# Checking the contents of a python list

Tags: python, list, collections, conditional-statements

Using python 2.7.4

Lets say I have a list

```
list = ['abc', 'def']
```

I want to find if it contains certain things. So I try:

```
 [IN:] 'abc' in list
[OUT:] True
 [IN:] 'def' in list
[OUT:] True
 [IN:] 'abc' and 'def' in list
[OUT:] True
```

But when I list.pop(0) and repeat that last test:

```
 [IN:] 'abc' and 'def in list
[OUT:] True
```

Even though:

```
list = ['def']
```

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because:

```
abc' and 'def' in list
```

is equivalent to:

```
('abc') and ('def' in list) #Non-empty string is always True
```

Use `'abc' in list and 'def' in list` or for multiple items you can also use `all()`

```
all(x in list for x in ('abc','def'))
```

<sub>Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's a built-in type.</sub>

Comment: Yeah, list was just for demonstrative purposes. Thanks!